# Ruby Regex with `/^/`

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my code:

```
['banana', 'anana', 'naan'].map do |food|
   food.reverse
end.select { |f| f.match /^a/ }
# => ["ananab", "anana"]
```

I wonder if this regex is used to find a word which include characters different from `"a"` (Negation) or if the regex matches a word, that begins with `"a"` (`ananab` and `anana` from my understanding).

Can someone help me a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what your question is.  Are you asking what the code you posted does, or how to exclude items from the array that contain the letter "a" ?

The code you posted:

```
['banana', 'anana', 'naan'].map do |food|
       food.reverse
    end.select { |f| f.match /^a/ }
```

does the following:

first it creates a new array were each element is reversed (assumes each element is a string)

so

```
['banana', 'anana', 'naan'].map do |food|
        food.reverse
  end
```

should result in an array like this:

```
["ananab", "anana", "naan"]
```

This is because map takes each element in the array and injects it into the block

```
do |food| 
  food.reverse 
end
```

which does a string reverse on each elemet and creates a new array were each element has been "mapped" to the reversed string

then the

```
 .select { |f| f.match /^a/ }
```

part will create another array from ["ananab", "anana", "naan"]
containing each element that begins with the letter a  (/^a/ means begins with "a")

resulting in the array

```
["ananab", "anana"]
```

If your question is how to exclude words containing the letter a then

```
['banana', 'anana', 'naan'].reject { |s| s.include?("a") }
```

should do what you want (as sawa pointed out)

Answer (score 3):

If you thought `^` means negation, that is so only when it is the first character in `[]`, which expresses character groups. Even if you have a negation `[^a]`, that does not mean a string that does not have the character `a`. It means a string that has a character other than `a`.

Regex is a tool to try to match something. In its implementation, it will try to match a pattern in any way possible by changing the match position, backtracking, etc. If you want to see if a string does not match a pattern, the most straightforward way is to use negation on the predicate, not on the regex. The following will return true when string `s` does not include an `a`:

```
s !~ /a/
```

But in such simple case, you can rather do:

```
!s.include?("a")
```

or instead of `select`, you can use `reject`:

```
reject{|s| s.include?("a")}
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex `/^a/` means: "match any string where the first character is an `a`". The `^` character here indicates the start of a string.

I believe what you're looking for is `/[^a]/`, which means: "match any string that contains a character that *is not* an `a`". The `[^...]` syntax will match any character *except* those within the braces.

To really get at what you want, throw a `*` on the end of there `/^[^a]*$/`, to say: "match any string where all the characters from start (`^`) to finish (`$`) *are not* `a`.

---

Addendum: As per the comments, anywhere I've written "string", I really mean "string *or* line". The `^` and `$` characters are *anchors*, pinning the regex to the start or end of the line. Or, in the case of a string without any newlines, it anchors to the start or end of the string.

Comment: `^` actually means beginning of *line*, not beginning of *string*. `\A` means beginning of string. Similarly, `$` is end of line whereas `\z` is end of string.

Comment: For posterity, it actually means the beginning of a line _or_ the beginning of a string. So, we're both technically wrong, though arguably, I'm more wrong. (But it actually was an intentional choice, for simplicity. Maybe misguided.)

Comment: @ceykooo But only because the beginning of a string must always also be the beginning of a line.

Comment: I sort of disagree. But it's a philosophical disagree. It's murkier for the end of a string: is the end of a string really the end of a line or was there no line at all? I must consult with my spiritual council.

Comment: @ceykooo As AndrewMarchall notes, your description "we're both technically wrong" is wrong. mu is too short is not wrong. Only you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
['banana', 'anana', 'naan'].map(&:reverse).select { |f| !f.include?("a") }
```

The code does the following: reverses the strings in the array and filters all strings that contain the character "a".

Comment: why reverse the strings, if you are just going to exclude those that have the letter "a"?

Comment: I only refactored the OP's code. I'm just the messenger.